# NHibernate one-to-one mapping with unique foreign key

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm seeing some unexpected query behavior with a one-to-one mapping where the "child" record is possibly null. Nhibernate seems to generate inner joins when it seems like a left join would be more appropriate. Given the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [CustomerId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccountNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [EmployeeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
    [PersonId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Customer_Person] FOREIGN KEY([PersonId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([PersonId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Customer_Person]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Person] FOREIGN KEY([PersonId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([PersonId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Person]
GO
```

And the following classes:

```
namespace OneToOneMapping.Model
{
    public class Person
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public virtual System.Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    }
    public class Customer
    {
        public virtual System.Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
        public virtual int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And mappings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="OneToOneMapping"
                   namespace="OneToOneMapping.Model">

  <class name="Person" table="Person" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id" column="PersonId">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="Customer" cascade="all-delete-orphan" property-ref="Person" class="OneToOneMapping.Model.Customer" />
    <one-to-one name="Employee" cascade="all-delete-orphan" property-ref="Person" class="OneToOneMapping.Model.Employee" />
    <property name="Name"/>
  </class>

  <class name="OneToOneMapping.Model.Customer, OneToOneMapping" table="Customer">
    <id name="Id" column="CustomerId">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="AccountNumber"/>
    <many-to-one name="Person" class="Person" column="PersonId" unique="true" cascade="save-update"/>
  </class>

  <class name="OneToOneMapping.Model.Employee, OneToOneMapping" table="Employee" lazy="true" mutable="true">
    <id name="Id" column="EmployeeId">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Title"/>
    <many-to-one name="Person" class="Person" column="PersonId" unique="true" cascade="save-update"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am unable to create a linq query where I can return a projection indicating whether a Customer is also an Employee (or vice versa). Running something like the following statement:

```
var t = Session.Query<Customer>().Select(c => new { AccountNumber = c.AccountNumber, Name= c.Person.Name, IsEmployee = c.Person.Employee.Id != null }).ToList();
```

Generates the following SQL (note the "where" clause prevents any Customer records that don't have also have an associated Employee record from returning at all):

```
    SELECT customer0_.AccountNumber AS col_0_0_
    ,person1_.NAME AS col_1_0_
    ,employee2_.EmployeeId AS col_2_0_
FROM Customer customer0_
LEFT JOIN Person person1_ ON customer0_.PersonId = person1_.PersonId
    ,Employee employee2_
WHERE person1_.PersonId = employee2_.PersonId
```

I'd expect it to generate something like the following to just return a null EmployeeId when the record does not exist:

```
SELECT customer0_.AccountNumber AS col_0_0_
    ,person1_.NAME AS col_1_0_
    ,employee2_.EmployeeId AS col_2_0_
FROM Customer customer0_
LEFT JOIN Person person1_ ON customer0_.PersonId = person1_.PersonId
Left Join Employee employee2_ on  person1_.PersonId = employee2_.PersonId
```

Am I missing something or is this a known issue with the "one-to-one" mapping?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your domain model.  Are you saying a person has a customer or an employee or are you trying to say whether a person is a customer or employee.   If it's the later then you need to be using inheritance mapping not a one to one mapping.

Comment: Ideally, it would be an inheritance model, but that won't work because a person can be both an employee **and** a customer. That would break polymorphic queries such as Session.Get<Person>(id). Instead, we consider the _person_ to be the common attributes that both an employee and a customer _have_.

Comment: That would be an any mapping and a base class query would return both sub classes.

Comment: How would an "any" mapping work for inheritance? I thought that was specifically for cases when there wasn't a base table/class, similar to this example: http://ayende.com/blog/3966/nhibernate-mapping-any

Answer (score 0):

We've identified a different query method using subqueries in the projections that seems to work. I believe the underlying issue is related to the open issue here: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3117?jql=text%20~%20%22one%20to%20one%22. It appears that the NHibernate linq provider doesn't properly handle one-to-one mappings where the referencing item(s) possibly doesn't exist.

The workaround:

```
var t = Session.Query<Customer>()
                .Select(c => new { 
                    AccountNumber = c.AccountNumber, 
                    Name= c.Person.Name, 
                    IsEmployee = Session.Query<Employee>().Any(e => e.Id == c.Person.Id)
                }).ToList();
```

Generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT customer0_.AccountNumber AS col_0_0_
    ,person1_.NAME AS col_1_0_
    ,CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT employee2_.EmployeeId
                FROM Employee employee2_
                WHERE employee2_.EmployeeId = customer0_.PersonId
                )
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS col_2_0_
FROM Customer customer0_
LEFT JOIN Person person1_ ON customer0_.PersonId = person1_.PersonId
```